# Fabricjs get font size while editing itext

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have text editor for itext in the canvas. I can change my font size when using this text editor panel. But when set font size to 60px and reset target and enter editing again it show me size like 40(default size). 
So how i can get font size while editing itext object? 
Cheers!
[image]

Comment: Please add what you accomplished so far.

Comment: There is probably some code in that fontsize slider that make difference between in edit mode and not. Post the code for it.